# Am I using the JointVelocityController correctly?

Tags: ros, ros-controllers, ros-control

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, ROS Hydro beta, and Gazebo 1.9.0 (the one that is installed with Hydro). When I use a JointVelocityController, I get the following error:

```
[ INFO] [1376543194.963746055, 0.937000000]: Loaded gazebo_ros_control.
gzserver: /opt/ros/hydro/include/hardware_interface/joint_state_interface.h:71: double hardware_interface::JointStateHandle::getVelocity() const: Assertion `vel_' failed.
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Instances of JointPositionController work correctly. Initially, I thought this problem was caused by a bug in Gazebo 1.9.0, but the assertion is failing in effort_controllers::JointVelocityController::update(), so the problem might be in ros_controllers. I've uploaded a test case to GitHub:

```
git clone https://github.com/wunderkammer-laboratory/ackermann_vehicle.git
```

To reproduce the error:

```
roslaunch ackermann_vehicle_gazebo ackermann_vehicle.launch
```

Am I using the JointVelocityController correctly?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/73426/am-i-using-the-jointvelocitycontroller-correctly?/) by [Jim Rothrock](https://answers.ros.org/users/274/jim-rothrock/) on ROS Answers with karma: 792 on 2013-08-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This problem does not exist in Gazebo 1.9.1.

---

Originally posted by [Jim Rothrock](https://answers.ros.org/users/274/jim-rothrock/) with karma: 792 on 2013-09-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0